# has Presenting modal view controller in iOS 4.3 for iPad changed?

Tags: ios4, modalviewcontroller

Has Presenting modal view controller in iOS 4.3 for iPad changed?

I created a new view application, then created a new UIViewControllerSubclass called "One", I then changed the background of One.xib to black, in the applications view controller's viewDidLoad method I placed in the code below. I ran the project in the simulator and receive the log that the "Code has run..."

The project can be downloaded from here....[Download Source Code of Project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8256776/Untitled.zip)

```
#import "One.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
One *newItemViewController = [[One alloc] initWithNibName:@"One" bundle:nil];
newItemViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:newItemViewController animated:YES];
[newItemViewController release];
NSLog(@"Code has run...");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your this in the viewDidAppear method instead of viewDidLoad.